# Automatically deploy git on servers not reachable

Tags: linux, git

I have several servers that can't be reach via SSH or HTTP directly but they are able to connect to internet.

I would like to find a smart way to deploy automatically updates via git. I could do a script that periodically do a git pull but it seems not the best way.

Which is the best way to manage git deploy in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into "git bundle"

I have used this in "air gapped" systems before.

```
git bundle create <file> <git-rev-list-args>

git bundle verify <file>
```

Once you create the bundle, you can use "git clone" or "git pull" against the bundle.

This is from the man page for "bundle":

> Some workflows require that one or more branches of development on one machine be replicated on another
>   machine, but the two machines cannot be directly connected, and therefore the interactive Git protocols (git,
>   ssh, rsync, http) cannot be used. This command provides support for git fetch and git pull to operate by
>   packaging objects and references in an archive at the originating machine, then importing those into another
>   repository using git fetch and git pull after moving the archive by some means (e.g., by sneakernet). As no
>   direct connection between the repositories exists, the user must specify a basis for the bundle that is held by
>   the destination repository: the bundle assumes that all objects in the basis are already in the destination
>   repository.

Comment: BTW: you just need to copy the bundle to a machine that you can reach from the other system and then copy the file over and just do a git pull from the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

> you just need to copy the bundle to a machine that you can reach from the other system and then copy the file over and just do a git pull from the bundle

Git 2.25 (Q1 2020) explains why.

See [commit 0e40a73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e40a73a4c768c220dabf14f173f33c87a4f4829) (20 Oct 2019) by [Philip Oakley (`PhilipOakley`)](https://github.com/PhilipOakley).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7c88714](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c887142621106a303a321b51b1958112ed2bf24), 10 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`Doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e40a73a4c768c220dabf14f173f33c87a4f4829): Bundle file usage
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philip Oakley</sup>
>
> Improve the command description, including paragraph spacing.
>
> Git URLs can accept bundle files for fetch, pull and clone, include in that section. Include [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) in the bundle usage description. Correct the quoting of `<git-rev-list-args>`.
>
> Detail the `<git-rev-list-args>` options for cloning a complete repo.

So the updated [`git bundle` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7c887142621106a303a321b51b1958112ed2bf24/Documentation/git-bundle.txt) now includes:

> The '`git bundle`' command packages objects and references in an archive at the originating machine, which can then be imported into another repository using '`git fetch`', '`git pull`', or '`git clone`', after moving the archive by some means (e.g., by sneakernet).

Also:

> `git clone` can use any bundle created without negative refspecs (e.g., `new`, but not `old..new`).
> If you want to match `git clone --mirror`, which would include your refs such as `refs/remotes/*`, use `--all`.
> If you want to provide the same set of refs that a clone directly from the source repository would get, use `--branches --tags` for the `<git-rev-list-args>`.